# Google spreadsheet script deleting new rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is really my first time trying to get a google script to work, so please excuse my inexperience.

I have a spreadsheet that I want to have rows deleted if it goes past a specific amount(eight in my case).

I think this should work but I must be missing something. My problem is no rows being deleted, but no errors being given either.

```
function killNewRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange();  

  if (data.length > 8) {
    for (var row = data.length; row >= 9; row--) {
       sheet.deleteRow(row);
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are special methods for this kind of routines... here is a working example :

```
function killNewRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var maxRow = sheet.getMaxRows();
  if(lastRow>8){
    sheet.deleteRows(9, maxRow-8);
  }
}
```

btw, note the `deleteRows(start,numberOfRows)` method that will be faster than deleting one by one every row.

---

EDIT : sheet example [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sbJXuEpL_88-u-Bm4QOCAM3SVddFwZKI0c1kxeRpcos/edit?usp=sharing), make your own copy and don't forget to add a trigger from **script editor > ressources > add new trigger > from spreadsheet > onChange**.

You can of course make that all automatic by simply adding an 'on change' trigger that calls this function.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate your help. I completely deleted what I was working on and made a new script copying exactly what you wrote, after adding an 'on change' trigger and authorizing the script to run it still was not deleting rows for me. Likely some user error on my end.

Comment: Added: The execution transcript shows it ending after this part even though the sheet I'm using it on has 28 rows at the moment              [14-02-14 16:26:33:863 AST] Sheet.getMaxRows() [0.015 seconds]
[14-02-14 16:26:33:864 AST] Execution succeeded [0.422 seconds total runtime]

Comment: I edited my answer with a link, please try it following recommendation about trigger.

Comment: Thank you! Realized what I was missing there.